# UFW wont delete rule

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I was testing something and added a rule to my firewall to allow port 9000.
in retrospect, I should have just disabled it temporarily.
anyhow, I went to remove the rule and it wont let me, it says rule not found.

```
$ sudo ufw delete 9000
ERROR: Could not find rule '9000'
```

but clearly, the rule is still active:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I read the UFW help and it says you can delete a port number, but it doesn't happen.
How can I remove the rule for port 9000 from UFW?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
sudo ufw delete allow 9000
```

If you make a rule by the following:

```
sudo ufw allow 9000
```

Then the rule is `allow 9000`. Now if you want to delete the rule:

```
sudo ufw delete rule
```

i.e.

```
sudo ufw delete allow 9000
```

Comment: @j0h: Happy to help :)

Comment: You can also print the rules numbered from one and up(ufw status numbered?) . And then you can delete them by giving the number(ufw delete 3?). Don't forget to read the man page for ufw(8) if you don't remember the syntax.

Comment: Good one! :-) Upvoted!

Comment: It didn't help me. I get the following message: "Could not delete non-existent rule Could not delete non-existent rule (v6)" But when checking the status it still appears

Comment: I found it out. Type sudo ufw status numbered. Then "sudo ufw delete # (number of rule, ex. 'sudo ufw delete 3')"

Answer (score 5):

The first step you can list all current rules by number:

```
$ sudo ufw status numbered
```

Then base on the listed numbers, you can delete rule by number. The number of the rule is shown in the leftmost column.

```
$ sudo ufw delete 2
```

You can refer to link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Gufw](http://gufw.org/) (A very user-friendly way to manage your Ubuntu Firewall, powered by [ufw](https://launchpad.net/ufw))

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can delete all rules for a specific port number in ufw (Port 3000 in this case) :

```
while true; do rule_number=$(ufw status numbered | awk '/(ALLOW|DENY) IN/ && $0 ~ /\<(3000)\>/{gsub(/[\[\]]/, ""); print $1; exit}'); if [ -z "$rule_number" ]; then break; else sudo yes | ufw delete $rule_number --force; fi; done
```